# Scala qualified protected member in subclass

Tags: scala, protected

In [Scala Language Spec.](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#protected) I found that

***A different form of qualification is protected[this]. A member M marked with this modifier is called object-protected; it can be accessed only from within the object in which it is defined. That is, a selection p.M is only legal if the prefix is this or O.this, for some class O enclosing the reference. In addition, the restrictions for unqualified protected apply***.

However I understand the case with ***this***
e.g
**`this.protectedMember`**

But what I didn't get is

***O.this, for some class O enclosing the reference*** .

please Help..

However as my understanding says that this is something that is realted with inner class as we do in **Swing** to get the outer class object eg
***OuterClass.this.someMethod*** in anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [The expression C.this is legal in the statement part of an enclosing class or object definition with simple name C. It stands for the object being defined by the innermost such definition.](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#this-and-super)

E.g. you can have

```
class O {
  class I {
    // O.this is the instance of O this I instance is nested in
    def M = ...
    M // calls M in I
    O.this.M // calls M in O
  }

  protected[this] def M = ...
}
```

Comment: yes,and if we need to access this member with instance of O we need to qualify the package where subclass can be found,Am i right ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I mean I understood what you said ,but If i need to access any protected member with an instance that is created by new eg . `val o=new O` and I do as `o.protectedMember` than i need to specify that member with protected[package_of_subclass], Am i right ?

Comment: No, you just need not to specify `[this]`. It exists specifically to disallow such calls.

Comment: I am accessing this protected member in subclass

Comment: And I am not seeing any difference b/w `protected` and `protected[this]` , is there any ?

Comment: As I said above, `protected[this]` doesn't allow `o.protectedMember`. `protected` does.